# Is Parallel.Foreach safe to assign values to target list items?

Tags: c#, multithreading, list, thread-safety

I have a source list with modified values and need to assing this changes to a second list with Parallel.Foreach.

I'm wondering if this is thread safe, code example:

```
Parallel.ForEach(sourceList, (srcItem) =>
{
    var destItem = destinationList.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == srcItem.Id);
    destItem.Color = srcItem.Color;
});
```

It's ok? or need to set some syncronization or locking?

Comment: Not an answer, but good read:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentbag-1?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Incomplete. What type/class is `destItem` ?

Comment: `destItem` is a DTO class with info of boxes, the `srcItem` type is a ViewModel class with the color and size thresholds for every box.

Comment: Seems a bit back to front. If you are interested in performance, that FirstOrDefault call is working against you. Depending on the size of that list, a dictionary using id as the key would outperform this even without parallel. Doing both will be faster still unless the list is tiny.

Comment: Also worth noting that the OrDefault will return null if not present, so the next line will give you a null reference exception.

Comment: Actually the concern is about the safety of parallelism. About the performance we can change to an optimized collection, but if it's no thread-safe will not work at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If conditions such

1) it's guaranteed that there is one-to-one mapping between source `id` and destination `id`

2) `destinationList` never changes during `Parallel.ForEach` and neither it's content, except assignment of the `Color`

It should be safe to run this code, and no synchronization is required.

Comment: and id field on the source list is distinct

Comment: Yes, is one-on-one, actually the code could be changed to `destinationList.Single()`, the lists never change only the properties of the `destItem`.

Comment: @scumbag: then, you can safely parallelize and no further synchronization is needed under this circumstances.